# java.lang.SecurityException: Writable dex file is not allowed. while updating target version to 34

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

After upgrading compileSDKVersion to 34, I am getting this exception on Android 14 devices.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Writable dex file '/data/data/com.swaraj.cdmsfm/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes11.dex' is not allowed.
```

Comment: If you have any questions then please put them in your post.

Comment: Most likely you are facing the new Write xor Execute policy of Android. So in all locations your application is allowed to write you are not allowed to execute code from. BTW: The used tags don't make much sense, gradle and AndroidStudio run on PC side, but the error messages seem to be runtime message from an Android device. So please in details what you are doing and where those error messages come from.

Comment: @avtar-lal have you fight this?

Comment: if you find solution for this then share with us

Comment: I had the same issue, my app started crashing in debug mode when targeting API level 34. It seems the source reason was that I was using an old Android Studio version ("Dolphin"). I upgraded to Android Studio "Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 1" and the issue went away. I hope this helps others coming across this issue.

Comment: I was using Android Studio Eel and this error suddenly comes up. Did a clean rebuild, and it was OK for a while, then the error occur again and my app crash. So finally upgraded to Hedgehog, and the issue disappears.